# how to achieve multi tenancy in redis?

Tags: redis

Since I am fairly new with redis, I am trying to explore options and see how can I achieve multi tenancy with redis.
I read some documentation on redisLabs official page and looks like redis cluster mode supports multi tenancy out of the box with redis enterprise.
I am wondering if such a solution for multi tenancy is available in sentinel mode as well?

I may be completely confused with the multi tenancy that redis enterprise provides. May be it works in a sentinel mode also but nothing seems very clear to me.

Can someone throw some light on multi tenancy in redis and what mode supports it?

Comment: Can you provide more details on your case ? different node for each tenant ? or distribution of the keys depending on the tenant on single multi-tenant database ?

Comment: Not different nodes for each tenant as my tenants would keep growing and I don't want a linear growth of nodes that way. Too costly and cumbersome. Not the latter as well as I don't want tenants to share databases. For real tenant resource isolation, I would want them to have separate databases.

Answer (score 6):

If you are going to use `redis-cluster`, then only one DB is supported.

> Redis Cluster does not support multiple databases like the stand alone version of Redis. There is just database 0 and the SELECT command is not allowed.

If you are not going to use cluster mode, then you may take a look on the message posted by the creator of Redis about multiple databases (years ago)

> I understand how this can be useful, but unfortunately I consider
>   Redis multiple database errors my worst decision in Redis design at
>   all... without any kind of real gain, it makes the internals a lot
>   more complex. The reality is that databases don't scale well for a
>   number of reason, like active expire of keys and VM. If the DB
>   selection can be performed with a string I can see this feature being
>   used as a scalable O(1) dictionary layer, that instead it is not.
>
> With DB numbers, with a default of a few DBs, we are communication
>   better what this feature is and how can be used I think. I hope that
>   at some point we can drop the multiple DBs support at all, but I think
>   it is probably too late as there is a number of people relying on this
>   feature for their work.

[Salvatore's message](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/vS5wX8X4Cjg/discussion)
[Redis cluster documentation](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec)

What i may suggest is prefixing. We are using this method in a SaaS application and all different data types are prefixed with related customer name. We handle some of the operations on application layer.

If you want to go single instance/multiple database then you need to manage them on your codebase via using `select` command. There may be some libraries to manage them. One of the critical thing is that;

> All databases are still persisted in the same RedisDB / Append Only file.

Comment: As per this article from redisLabs https://redislabs.com/blog/multi-tenancy-redis-enterprise/ multi tenancy is supported out of the box in redis enterprise where the client doesn't need to manage anything. Based on how it explains the architecture, I think I just need to decide on a shard key which would be tenant id and different shards will be managed seamlessly in either single or different Dbs and I would have HA as well as it can replicate shards across DBs. Do you think redis enterprise would be the solution here ?

Comment: Couldn't find the pricing for this, since they are going to add a service cost or any additional cost(managing or maintenance) then it will be probably more expensive than your managed one. Other than that; it fits to your use case.